# Upper bound rush hour game

Tags: algorithm, upperbound

I'm trying to understand the upper bound complexity for a [Rush Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_(puzzle)) game puzzle. I'm dealing with a `9x9` board, with `22` vehicles, including trucks (3 grids long) and cars (2 grids long).

By my logic, given the fact that a car can move `8 times` over a `9x9` board in one direction, the calculation would be `8^22`, which results in `7.34e+19`. This implies that the upper bound is `7.34e+19` different states for this puzzle.

It seems too excessive to me, for I want to calculate how close my algorithm to a solution is, given the number of iterated board states. Even supposing that all vehicles are trucks and therefore could only move `7` times seems too large.

Is my upper bound overestimated? Perhaps I should consider that the amount of movable space is the only space not occupied by a vehicle.

Comment: What exactly is a "complexity" for a game puzzle? Are you trying to solve the puzzle efficiently, simply calculate all "distinct" (in some sense) states, or something else?

Comment: @yeputons I added the keyword 'complexity' in my edit as the original just mentioned 'upper bound' which I assumed related to probably some kind of upper bound complexity (computational, logic, etc). My apologies if the edit caused some confusion. Please see here the revision of the original post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50990910/revisions

Comment: This might be useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0502068.pdf

Comment: https://www.michaelfogleman.com/rush/